# Excel macro - can any one explain this?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

I am new to Excel macros..

Can anyone tell me what this macro does?

```
Sub People_Add_Document()

    prow = ActiveCell.row
    num = Cells(prow, 1).Value
    wshet = ActiveSheet.Name

    If (Val(num) > 0) _
       And (Cells(4, 1).Value = "#") _
       And (wsheet = People_wsheet) _
    Then
        people_select_link_to_Document process_wbook_path, prow
    End If
  End Sub



Sub people_select_link_to_Document(process_wbook_path, prow)

        If Len(Cells(prow, DocumentFile).Value) = 0 Then
        Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename("Document Files (*.doc;*.pdf),*.doc;*.pdf", 1, "Select the Document file..")

        If Fname <> False Then

            Cells(prow, DocumentFile).Value = Fname 'global path

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the row number of the active cell:

```
prow = ActiveCell.row
```

Get the value in column 1 of that row:

```
num = Cells(prow, 1).Value
```

Read the name of the active worksheet (there is an error here, should read `wsheet` rather than `wshet`):

```
wshet = ActiveSheet.Name
```

Test if `num` is greater than 0, and the cell A4 contains "#" and the active worksheet is equal to a variable or constant called `People_wsheet`. And if so, a subroutine called `people_select_link_to_Document` is called with parameters `process_wbook_path` and `prow`

```
If (Val(num) > 0) _
   And (Cells(4, 1).Value = "#") _
   And (wsheet = People_wsheet) _
Then
    people_select_link_to_Document process_wbook_path, prow
End If
```

Now, that subroutine first of all checks to see if the `DocumentFile` column of the active row is empty. Actually it's a rather lame way to test emptyness, but it will probably do.

```
    If Len(Cells(prow, DocumentFile).Value) = 0 Then
```

And if it is empty then we show a file dialog to obtain a file name:

```
    Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename("Document Files (*.doc;*.pdf),*.doc;*.pdf", 1, "Select the Document file..")
```

If a filename has been selected (i.e. the dialog is not cancelled) then we save that file name in the `DocumentFile` column of the active row for future reference:

```
    If Fname <> False Then

        Cells(prow, DocumentFile).Value = Fname 'global path

    End If
```

And that's it!